# Como desabilitar o duplo clique no cabeçalho de um DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, header, datagrid

Método de duplo clique no grid:

```
    private void grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && //Verifica clique com o esquerdo
          uldPo00100.SelectedItems.Count > 0) //Verifica item selecionado 
          //Comandos para abrir nova janela
```

Normalmente, no clique simples, é selecionado um item do grid, e no duplo clique, executa o método acima.

Problema: Quando um item está selecionado, e dou um duplo clique no cabeçalho, ou na parte em branca do grid, é executado o método igual..

Existe uma verificação se o duplo clique é na linha mesmo, ou diferente do cabeçalho? Ou existe algum evento de clique no cabeçalho?
Lembrando que é DataGrid, não DataGridView..

Comment: Você pode tentar pegar a célula sob o cursor de acordo com essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25503438/1291717 e então decidir o que fazer com o handle do duplo clique

Answer (score 0):

Remova o handler do evento

```
 EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler(dataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick);
 dataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick -= eventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito não ser possível desabilitar. Como alternativa você pode ignorar o douplo clique no cabeçalho:

```
private void grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = grid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```